# How do I use best-in-place after jquery-file-upload in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-file-upload, best-in-place

I'm using the jquery fileupload gem to add productimages in my application. After the image upload is done, the images and the image settings are rendered into the current page. The image settings can be changed using the best in place gem. The issue is now, that all best_in_place input fields (all but the checkbox fields) are not available until I reload the current page. By not available I mean I can not access the best_in_place fields. I'm confused because the checkbox fields are working fine.

**Productimage partial:**

```
<%= image_tag(productimage.image_url(:thumb_q_small).to_s) %>
Visible: <%= best_in_place productimage, :active, :type => :checkbox, :collection => ["N", "Y"] %><br>
Name: <%= best_in_place productimage, :name %>
```

**The form field:**

```
<%= form_for Productimage.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :image, "Add productimages:" %><br>
  <%= file_field_tag :image, multiple: true, name: "productimage[image]" %>
<% end %>
```

**productimages.js.coffee:**

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

jQuery ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()

jQuery ->
  $('#new_productimage').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
    add: (e, data) ->
      types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
      file = data.files[0]
      if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
        data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
        $('#new_productimage').append(data.context)
        data.submit()
      else
        alert("#{file.name} is not a gif, jpeg, or png image file")
    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
```

**And this is finally the code snippet (just for the name) that is created after a image upload:**

```
Name: <span id="best_in_place_productimage_124_name" class="best_in_place" data-type="input" data-attribute="name" data-object="productimage" data-url="/productimages/124"></span>
```

Thanks & regards, Andreas

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it looks like the issue is the missing default value like "-". So the input field is 0px x 0px and can not be clicked.

My workaround is to add some css like this:

```
.best_in_place {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #00F;
  min-width: 20px;
}
```

But any better answer is still very welcome :)